# Extremely high usage of Google Translate API. Why could that happen?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

This is my first post here. I have been working with my team on an event website (currently between 50-100 events). We implemented the Google Translate API and the daily usage is around 500k characterers (so the first day, I already consume the free quote). It could be that we are not very familiar to the API, but is this usage normal?

Does anybody have information on the actual inner usage of the Google Translate API? Does it translate the whole page every time or how does it work? Anybody came up with any reason why this could happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Translation API, you can translate a web page by using the translating feature either [Basic](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text) or [Advanced](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3). See [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) and [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas) for more information. By using the Translation API, all the text on the page will be translated. You will get a response only with the (untranslated) HTML tags and with the translated text between the tags. In addition, I suggest you take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/markup) where you can find the HTML markup requirements. Please find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254664/how-to-translate-whole-page-text-content-in-js-with-google-translate-api) in Stack Overflow.