# How can I translate entire Angular Website without writing separate language file

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have an angular 7+ application for which I want to have multiple language support.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview internationalization is the keyword you are looking for

Comment: A language file is mandatory. Otherwise how will you do this? Put all language strings in all components? This would be messy and very, very hard to maintain.

Comment: I want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254664/how-to-translate-whole-page-text-content-in-js-with-google-translate-api